# Using Shell to Check Whether a File Exists, and only if it does, Execute a Set of Commands

Tags: shell, stata

I have a few lines of code in Stata.  I'd like the lines to be executed only if the .txt file to which the lines refer exist a priori.  I am wondering whether there is a shell command that I can use for this that I can embed in an `if` statement.

For example might something like the following exist and be possible:

```
 insheet using "file.txt" if ('file.txt')
```

My intent is to say `insheet` the file `file.txt` only if it exists.  My concern is that the program would otherwise stop, fail, die, or whatever you call it due to a syntax error if I have that `insheet` statement but the file does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediate answer is No. There is nothing like that syntax for several reasons.

1. The `if` qualifier tests whether some condition is true separately for each observation and whether a file exists is not an appropriate condition for testing observation by observation.
2. The quite different `if` command tests once and once only whether something is true and might seem more appropriate. In practice it is not used for this purpose, but to learn more, see `help ifcmd`.
3. Stata has no special syntax based on paired identical single quotes `' '`.

However, Stata provides a separate construct here

```
confirm file file.txt
```

In practice that is going to stop a do-file or program whenever the file does not exist and the file does not exist. A general scheme to catch the error is something like

```
capture confirm file file.txt 
if _rc == 0 insheet using file.txt 
else { 
    <code if the file does not exist> 
}
```

`capture` is to be thought of as eating the return code from the `confirm` command. In general the return code `_rc` from any command is 0 if the command was valid and executed and some non-zero value otherwise. Sometimes one tests for a specific non-zero code. Experiment shows that `file not found` is return code 601. The main reason for looking up error codes (in [P] error) is to deliver official-looking error messages, but in practice knowing the zero/non-zero rule is the main detail under this heading.

The example here uses `==` to test for equality.

Note that `insheet using file.txt` is not strictly a syntax error if the file does not exist. As far as Stata's language is concerned, that is legal syntax. However, that is a fine distinction: it is an error in every ordinary sense.

(LATER) It would be possible to short-circuit the entire process

```
 capture insheet using file.txt 
 if _rc != 0 { 
      <code if the file does not exist>
 }
```

as in this case the non-existence of the file is the presumed explanation for any failure of the `insheet` command. If, however, the `insheet` call were more complicated, with a *varlist* and/or options, then failure of the command could arise for other reasons. So in general separating out a check for the existence of the file seems a better strategy.

Answer (score 3):

The `confirm` command has what you're looking for.

```
capture confirm file "file.txt"
if !_rc {  # if the file exists, confirm will return error code 0
    insheet using "file.txt"
}
```

Alternatively, you could put a `capture` before the `insheet` command, which will catch the syntax error. Check the [P] manual for more on `capture` and `confirm`.